# Mule async scope with flow ref and flow variables

Tags: mule

I have a thread safety issue around the async scope and flow variables and flow-ref component.

Take the following for example:

```
<flow>
   <set-variable variableName="numericalValue" value="5" />
   <async>
      <flow-ref name="calculate" />
   </async>

   <set-variable variableName="numericalValue" value="10" />
   <async>
      <flow-ref name="calculate" />
   </async>
</flow>
```

Im guessing the flow var "numericalValue" could be changed from 5 to 10 before the first flow-ref is actually processed?

Is it safer to do the following:

```
<flow>

   <async>
      <set-variable variableName="numericalValue" value="5" />
      <flow-ref name="calculate" />
   </async>


   <async>
      <set-variable variableName="numericalValue" value="10" />
      <flow-ref name="calculate" />
   </async>
</flow>
```

Can someone explain how this would work?

PS. 
My calculate flow is a private asynchronous flow:

```
<flow name="calculate" processingStrategy="asynchronous">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both approaches are prone to issues. Let me explain why.

As you can see here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/processor/AsyncDelegateMessageProcessor.java#L112

```
// Clone event and make it async
MuleEvent newEvent = new DefaultMuleEvent(
        (MuleMessage) ((ThreadSafeAccess) event.getMessage()).newThreadCopy(), event, false);
```

Mule clones the event before processing the `async` block. So one could think that all is good and the cloned event is disconnected from the original event.

That is unfortunately not the case because the cloned-event is backed by the flow variables of the original event, as seen here: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/DefaultMuleEvent.java#L328

```
if (rewriteEvent instanceof DefaultMuleEvent)
{
    this.processingTime = ((DefaultMuleEvent) rewriteEvent).processingTime;
    this.flowVariables = ((DefaultMuleEvent) rewriteEvent).flowVariables;
}
```

Then the Mule Message gets a reference to these flow variables here https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/DefaultMuleEvent.java#L953 so they can be accessed on it via the `Invocation` property scope.

All this leads to the fact that flow variables changed in one thread will be visible in another thread.

So if you want complete isolation create another flow variable or use outbound message properties, the latter being copied not cross-referenced per: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/core/src/main/java/org/mule/DefaultMuleMessage.java#L222